# Sheets: Count Row data Based on Key

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

Im trying to find a Row based on a value, and count the number of entries (Max 5) in that row.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2 | 2 |  | 5 | 4 |  |
| 2 | Mary | 1 | 3 | 1 | 6 |  | 7 |

`=COUNTA(B1:GZ)` will work if I knew the row for "John",

but im trying to get the row based on a value from another cell ...

|  | Z |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | John |

In this case `Z10` pseudo: `=COUNTA(Find Z10 in Col A, then count entries in Row starting at B to Z)`

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: try this formula `=ArrayFormula(countif(A:A&(B:Z<>""),AB2&True))` where `AB2` - is the cell with the name you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

**Recommendation:**

You can try this method

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(A1:Z, "Select * where A = '"&Z10&"'"))-1
```

**Sample**

*Sample sheet:*

[image]

1. `John` added on cell `Z10`
2. The recommended function added on cell `Z11`

**Result**: 4 was the result of `COUNTA` on the rows B:Z based on Column A that contains the value "John"

[image]

**NOTE:**

You may need to turn on [Iterative calculation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515) on your Spreadsheet settings.